# Counting solutions to linear inequalities

Tags: algorithm, math, counting

I am trying to solve a problem which I have reduced down to counting the number of *integer* solutions to a number of linear inequalities. I need to be able to count the number of solutions for any number of variables c_1, ..., c_n, but for n=3 the equations could be written as:

[The equations. http://silicon.appspot.com/readdoc?id=155604](http://silicon.appspot.com/readdoc?id=155604)

Now, I know the values of n and r in advance and wish to find the number of (c_1, ..., c_n) solutions that exist.

Can this be done efficiently (faster than enumerating the solutions)? (If so: how?; if not: why?)

Comment: You show a 4x3 matrix being multiplied by a 3x1 matrix. Therefore the result is a 4x1 matrix. What does it mean to say that a 4x1 matrix is at least zero and at most nine?

Comment: Please fix the Q ... this reminds me of mixed integer programming somewhat, except ... | Now, how about this: Treat inequalities as half-planes, compute the intersection of all regions - should give you a polygon. If some of it's coordinates are +/- infinity, then you either have an infinite number, or zero solutions (I think). Otherwise find a bounding rect. for the polygon, do two nested for loops inside of it, and check if every dot is inside the polygon (you will need to triangulate it). Worst case - bounding box is O(n^2) but you get O(n) solutions. Computational Geometry is your friend.

Comment: Hm ... in this particular example you only have to enumerate through (0,0,0) ... (9,9,9) (as long as the matrix has non-negative integers)

Comment: What is `r`? (A comment requires at least 15 characters for some reason.)

Comment: @Jason: That's a good question and I'm probably abusing notation doing that. I mean that each element in that 4×1 matrix satisfies those conditions.

Comment: @Svante: Thanks! Image fixed again to show r correctly.

Comment: I think these are called Diophantine Inequalities (all integers, right?)... http://www.addebook.com/tech/mathematics/diophantus-and-diophantine-equations_10070.html

Comment: @lpthnc: I follow your method up until the bounding rectangle. Surely I'd need more dimensions than 2 considering n may be 10. I agree, this is a geometry problem!

And, yes, this example is trivial.

Comment: My approach is probably not the best. I was concerned about the possibility that you might have unbounded regions to worry about. This does not seem to be the case. I like some of the answers here better.

Comment: Is *r* necessarily positive? Is it an integer?

Comment: I ask because ...well, I might be crazy, but it seems like you might be able to get a painless dynamic-programming solution or even a closed-form answer for this.

Comment: Another question: is it to be assumed that (c_1, ..., c_n) are nonnegative? Note that if r=2, then c=[5, -1, 4] satisfies the inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you had some code to produce all the solutions.

(For the parameter *z* here, pass 9. It's the number on the right-hand side of the inequalities. Note that this code only works when *r* is positive.)

```
from math import floor, ceil

def iter_solutions(r, n, z):
    c = [None] * n
    def iter_solutions_bounded(k, pick):
        # pick is the last pick, if any, and 0 otherwise
        assert (1 <= k < n and pick == c[k]) or (k == n and pick == 0)

        min_ck = int(ceil(-pick / r))
        max_ck = int(floor((z - pick) / r))
        if k == 1:
            for ck in range(max(min_ck, 0), min(max_ck, z) + 1):
                c[0] = ck
                yield c
        else:
            for ck in range(min_ck, max_ck + 1):
                c[k - 1] = ck
                for soln in iter_solutions_bounded(k - 1, ck):
                    yield soln
    return iter_solutions_bounded(n, 0)
```

You can convert this into code that merely *counts* the solutions simply by deleting all the code that refers to `c` and adding up the number of solutions that would have been yielded. Finally, you can improve the performance by memoization.

```
from math import floor, ceil

def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    def g(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        tmp = cache[args] = f(*args)
        return tmp
    return g

def len_range(a, b):
    if a <= b:
        return b - a
    return 0

def count_solutions(r, n, z):
    @memoize
    def count_solutions_bounded(k, pick):
        min_ck = int(ceil(-pick / r))
        max_ck = int(floor((z - pick) / r))
        if k == 1:
            return len_range(max(min_ck, 0), min(max_ck, z) + 1)
        else:
            return sum(count_solutions_bounded(k - 1, ck) for ck in range(min_ck, max_ck + 1))
    return count_solutions_bounded(n, 0)
```

Some possible improvements:

- If it's true that *c*<sub>1</sub> ... *c*<sub>n</sub> are always ≤ *z*, then detecting that and immediately returning 0 would help a lot for large *n*. In fact it would reduce the running time to a lightning-fast O(*nz*).
- If it is intended that *c*<sub>1</sub> ... *c*<sub>n</sub> all be non-negative, that's even better. Making the appropriate changes to `min_ck` and `max_ck` would make this O(*nz*) with a smaller constant, and the cache could be a flat 2D array instead of the slower hash table I've got.
- You might be able to do better by building the cache systematically, rather than populating it "on demand" the way this memoization code does. First build the whole cache for n=1, then for n=2, and so on. That way you could avoid recursion, and at each step you could throw away the cached data you no longer need (after calculating the results for n=2, you don't need the entries for n=1 anymore).

Comment: This seems the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I would probably go into the realms of constraint programming. It seems like you have a classic `all different` constraint (a bit like the N-Queens problem). Have a go at one of the free constraint solvers listed below. That will give you a solution quite efficiently. It'll basically generate the whole search tree but with the nice All-Different constraint implementations out there, the tree will end up being pruned almost to nothing.

http://www.gecode.org/
http://minion.sourceforge.net/
http://jacop.osolpro.com/
http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64335

Here's the wikipedia list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Constraint_programming_libraries_for_imperative_programming_languages

Comment: My only concern is that there will be too many solutions to count for large values of n.

Comment: True. I would say that for `N > 100` it will get pretty slow to find all solutions but I can't see another way that will cope with large values of N very well. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a full solution to your problem, but I think it may help or at least give you some ideas.

Your requirement that the solutions be integer makes this an NP problem. If we first consider the relaxation of the problem so that the domain is the real numbers, you are asking to solve the satisfiability problem of 0 <= A*c <= 1, where A is a matrix and c is your vector of unknowns. This is a standard linear program (LP with trivial objective), and can be solved efficiently (in polynomial time). You may want to use this as a first pass test to determine feasibility since if the relaxed LP has no solutions, your integer LP certainly has no solutions. A good LP solver will also return a feasible point if possible, and you may be able to round the vector's entries to find an integer solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, if you wanted to maximize a linear objective function based on these constraints then you would have an [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) problem, for which no efficient general solution exists. Instead you seem to be asking for the number of points in the [feasible region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region), which is a different problem, but it too is complicated by having to have integer solutions.

The best idea I can come up with involves finding the points on the boundary of the feasible region, and using those to determine the number of points inside. This works well at accelerating "count the lattice points" type problems in lower dimensions, but the boundary is still just one dimension smaller than the volume in question. If your problem gets over a few dimensions then the problem will still be intractable, even if it is faster than enumerating all the solutions.